# python - np array containing (R,G,B, X,Y) of pixels in an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel, np

I am currently trying to get a list of pixels that contains their rgb and the x and y values of each individual pixel. I can currently get a flattened list of all the pixels.

```
import Image
im = Image.open('Lenna.png')
pixels = np.array(im.getdata())
```

This will get you a flat list of RGB data that looks like:

[(226, 137, 125), (226, 137, 125), (223, 137, 133), (223, 136, 128), 
 (226, 138, 120), (226, 129, 116), (228, 138, 123), (227, 134, 124), 
 (227, 140, 127), (225, 136, 119), (228, 135, 126), (225, 134, 121),.

However, this wont give me any information of the x and y coordinates of each pixel. Are there any suggestions i can get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the (x,y) coordinate values from an image array's RGB value using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687572/get-the-x-y-coordinate-values-from-an-image-arrays-rgb-value-using-numpy)

Comment: That's a rather unusual approach. You normally know the coordinates implicitly through the indices into your array. Why do you want the coordinates explicitly - what do you plan to do with them next?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter pixels, you can check the answer to [the question mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687572/get-the-x-y-coordinate-values-from-an-image-arrays-rgb-value-using-numpy)

If you need the coordinates of all pixels, the following code may help:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


img = Image.open('/your_pic.png')
width, height = img.size
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(width), range(height))

coordinate = np.concatenate([img.getdata(), x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=1)
```

Then you will get a ndarray with [R,G,B,Alpha,X,Y].

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255,   1,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255,   2,   0],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 663, 665],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 664, 665],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 665, 665]])
```